# a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

Tags: arduino, serial-port

I'm trying to send a value `value` through the serial port to another Arduino when a certain input is detected (pin 7 is in the high state). In the below code I get the following error when compiling:

```
'test' was not declared in this scope
```

If I unhide the void `send`, that is inside the loop I get another error:

```
a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
```

The code:

```
    void setup() {
      SoftwareSerial test (3, 2);
      test.begin(1200);
      pinMode(7, INPUT);
     }

     void loop() {
      if ( digitalRead(7) == HIGH ) {
       // void send() {
        test.write(int value = 0);
        a++;
        delay(1000);
       // }
      }
     }
```

Expected result

Create a void that transmits a number that increases in each cycle.

Comment: `test` is defined in the scope of the `setup` method, so isn't available in the scope of the `loop` method. Move the declaration out of `setup` so it's available in both methods.

Comment: And regarding the `send` method. Your trying to define it within the `loop` method. Move it out and just call it from there. With `test` declared outside of any method, it'll be available from all three.

Comment: Move the declaration of `a` out of all methods too. If you want to increment the value each call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors of the code are:

- Wrong function calling.
- Wrong function declaration.

Let's solve them:

## Wrong serial calling

To correctly initialize the serial communication we need to assign the variable name followed by the pins.

`SoftwareSerial test(3, 2)`

If we write a space between, the IDLE doesn't know which are the pins you want to use. 
More precisely, you're calling a method of the [SofwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial) library called SoftwareSerial() that needs to attributes, the rxPin (where the Arduino board receives the data) and the txPin (where the Arduino board sends or transmits the data). You can also give an optional value, the inverse_logic boolean. So, when you type `SoftwareSerial test (3,2)` you aren't given the needed values for the method.

> This error can be applied to any method call. We call it 'call'
>   because you're not defining the method, you're just using it. You
>   don't need to know how does it work. It is enough knowing that you
>   need to give the two values, and the output you will receive. **The
>   values needed by the function are always given inside round brackets,
>   following the variable without any spaces. The returned values will be
>   stored in the variable you created, in this case, `test`**.

Now that we understand the cause of the problem `'test' was not declared in this scope` let's move to the next one.

## Wrong function declaration

Let's suppose that, instead of calling a function, we want to create a new one. We can do it, but following a series of rules:

- Specify the returned variable. It can be anything you want, a Boolean var (False or True), a number, etc. Maybe that method doesn't return anything, in this cases, we use the keyword `void`. In this case, we don't want to receive anything, so our method declarations start with `void`:

```
    void
```

- Assign a name for that function, in this case, we'll call it `send`:

```
    void send
```

- Specify the needed values. The needed attributes are given inside the round brackets. You need to specify the name for that variable and its type. If you need more than value, you separate them by adding `,`: `(int value, Boolean otherValue)`. If you don't need a value, just write `()`. in this case, we need the value we want to send.

```
    void send(String message){
```

- Return the specified value. In this case, nothing, so we don't type anything.

```
    void send(String message){
        test.write(message);
    }
```

More information about declaring a function can be found [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/FunctionDeclaration).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i fixed your code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
    SoftwareSerial test(3, 2);
    int a=0;
     void setup() {
      test.begin(1200);
      pinMode(7,INPUT);

     }

     void loop() {
      if ( digitalRead(7) == HIGH ) {
       //void send(){

        test.write(a);
        a++;
        delay(1000);
       //}
      }

     }
```

`test` must be declared outside the `setup()` function

Comment: thanks for the help. Also, if I write the send function out of the void loop it works, but isn't there any form of defining 'a' inside test.write()?

Comment: you can use the variable 'a' defined previously as a parameter for the send() function, then pass it to the test.write(a) function: void send(int var){....}. i wish this will help you